# Redux object Object is not extensible error when creating new attribute for array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

i need to delete a property to an object or delete based on the user action- if the selected property is already added , i need to remove this proporty if its not added i have to remove this

```
const { customAllAreas } = useSelector((state) => state.AreasReducer);
  const saveArea = (area) => {
    const newFilteredAreas = customAllAreas?.map((f) => {
      if (f?._id === area?._id) {
        if (f.selected) {
          delete f.selected;
        } else {
          f.selected = true;
        }
        return f;
      }
      return f;
    });
    dispatch(AreasAction.setcustomeAddedAreas(newFilteredAreas));
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the `customAllAreas` that is stored in redux.

```
delete f.selected; // mutation

f.selected = true; // mutation
```

You should make a copy of `customAllAreas` before doing so.

```
const newFilteredAreas = [...customAllAreas].map((...))
```

Or try the immutable way:

```
const newFilteredAreas = customAllAreas?.map((f) => {
  if (f?._id === area?._id) {
    if (f.selected) {
      const { selected, ...rest } = f;
      return rest;
    } else {
      return { ...f, selected: true };
    }
  }

  return f;
});
```

Comment: tried but not working--const newFilteredAreas = [...customAllAreas]?.map((f) => {
      if (f?._id === area?._id) {
        if (f.selected) {
          delete f.selected;
        } else {
          f.selected = true;
        }
        return f;
      }
      return f;
    });

Comment: @Andaman Try to remove both of the lines I posted above. Just to check if the error will be gone

Comment: Kind user- If i remove both lines ,then how can i add and delete selected property

Comment: @Andaman Just try the _immutable_ way instead of direct mutation as e.g. `delete f` :) Check my updated answer.